# Best way to learn Ext JS for use with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, extjs

I have very basic knowledge of Javascript and now I am looking forward to learn Ext JS and implement in in my ASP.NET application.

If anyone can guide me on how to start and which book I should follow, I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

Nor sure if it is the quickest approach, but all I did (as well as another developer that was working with me) was review the ExtJS documentation and samples gallery (and viewing their source).

One big issue to watch out for when using ExtJS with ASP.NET is that when using BorderLayout you will go crazy trying to figure out why Postbacks no longer work.  [There is a workaround](http://extjs.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-14261.html) though.

Another ASP.NET gotcha is that if you use ExtJS to talk with ASP.NET web services (or WCF) you have to do some special things to get it to work (adorn your webmethod with special attributes, or add some things to web.config, etc).

Those were the only two gotchas I can recall, other than just learning and getting the hang of ExtJS itself.